# Migration xml to Sql script

Tags: sql, database, spring, migration, liquibase

I am working on a spring framework project. Where earlier I was crating database using liquibase by db.changelog-master.xml.

Now my requirement is to ignore to create DB structure by liquibase (DO NOT WANT TO RUN MIGRATION)
So I want a sql script from this db.changelog-master.xml
how can I get it, is there any ways to generate it.
I am using ORACLE for it.

```
   <changeSet author="admin (generated)" id="1390535812881-1">
        <createTable catalogName="openskye" tableName="customer">
            <column name="cust_id" type="NVARCHAR(5)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="full_name" type="NVARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="email" type="NVARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="address" type="NVARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="phone" type="NVARCHAR(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Should convert to following query...

```
Create table openskye.customer (cust_id varchar(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, full_name varchar(255), email varchar(255), address varchar(255), phone varchar(255))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at updateSql command: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html